# How to scrape full paper citation from Google Scholar search results (Python)?

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-scholar

I am trying to web scrape some useful data on academic papers from Google Scholar.
So far I've had no problem getting the Title, Year of publication, Citation count, and "Cited by" URL.

I would like now to get the full citation that includes the full authors' list, journal, pages (if any) etc... (see snapshot below)
[Full APA citation appearing when clicking on the double quote (circled in red)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0Mof.png)

I use ScraperAPI to handle proxies and CAPTCHAs (they offer 5000 requests for free).

Below is the code I have (I'm aware it's very heavy and not optimal at all, but does the job for now):

```py
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

APIKEY = "????????????????????"
BASE_URL = f"http://api.scraperapi.com?api_key={APIKEY}&url="

def scraper_api(query, n_pages):
    """Uses scraperAPI to scrape Google Scholar for 
    papers' Title, Year, Citations, Cited By url returns a dataframe
    ---------------------------
    parameters:
    query: in the following format "automation+container+terminal"
    n_pages: number of pages to scrape
    ---------------------------
    returns:
    dataframe with the following columns: 
    "Title": title of each papers
    "Year": year of publication of each paper
    "Citations": citations count
    "cited_by_url": URL given by "cited by" button, reshaped to allow further
                    scraping
    ---------------------------"""

    pages = np.arange(0,(n_pages*10),10)
    papers = []
    for page in pages:
        print(f"Scraping page {int(page/10) + 1}")
        webpage = f"https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start={page}&q={query}&hl=fr&as_sdt=0,5"
        url = BASE_URL + webpage
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        
        for paper in soup.find_all("div", class_="gs_ri"):
            # get the title of each paper
            title = paper.find("h3", class_="gs_rt").find("a").text
            if title == None:
                title = paper.find("h3", class_="gs_rt").find("span").text
            # get the year of publication of each paper
            txt_year = paper.find("div", class_="gs_a").text
            year = re.findall('[0-9]{4}', txt_year)
            if year:
                year = list(map(int,year))[0]
            else:
                year = 0
            # get number of citations for each paper
            txt_cite = paper.find("div", class_="gs_fl").find_all("a")[2].string
            if txt_cite:
                citations = re.findall('[0-9]+', txt_cite)
                if citations:
                    citations = list(map(int,citations))[0]
                else:
                    citations = 0
            else:
                citations = 0
            # get the "cited_by" url for later scraping of citing papers
            # had to extract the "href" tag and then reshuffle the url as not
            # following same pattern for pagination
            urls = paper.find("div", class_="gs_fl").find_all(href=True)
            if urls:
                for url in urls:
                    if "cites" in url["href"]:
                        cited_url = url["href"]
                        index1 = cited_url.index("?")
                        url_slices = []
                        url_slices.append(cited_url[:index1+1])
                        url_slices.append(cited_url[index1+1:])

                        index_and = url_slices[1].index("&")
                        url_slices.append(url_slices[1][:index_and+1])
                        url_slices.append(url_slices[1][index_and+1:])
                        url_slices.append(url_slices[3][:23])
                        del url_slices[1]
                        new_url = "https://scholar.google.com.tw"+url_slices[0]+"start=00&hl=en&"+url_slices[3]+url_slices[1]+"scipsc="
            else:
                new_url = "no citations"
            # appends everything in a list of dictionaries    
            papers.append({'title': title, 'year': year, 'citations': citations, 'cited_by_url': new_url})
    # converts the list of dict to a pandas df
    papers_df = pd.DataFrame(papers)
    return papers_df
```

I would like to retrieve the full APA citation but seems like it's not on the same HTML page and there are no `href` associated.

If you have any lead that would help me a lot!! Thanks :)

Comment: You could always try including e.g. [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) in your scraping to emulate clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Open F12, go under the network tab then click on "citation symbol". You should see a request appear. The url of the request is as :

"https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=info:dgGDGDdf5:scholar.google.com/&output=cite&scirp=0&hl=fr"

where "dgGDGDdf5" is the "data-cid" findable in each div-row of the main page. Each "data-cid" correspond to an unique article.

So, extract this "data-cid" and make a sub-request with this url then extract APA or other citation form.

Implementation example :

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.parse import urlencode

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0"}
def google_scholar(query, n_pages, since_year):
    data = []
    encoded_query = urlencode({"q": query})
    for start in range(0, n_pages*10, 10):
        url = "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_ylo=%s&%s&hl=fr&start=%s" % (since_year, encoded_query, start)
        resp = rq.get(url, headers=headers)
        soup = bs(resp.content, "lxml")
        print(soup)
        main_div = soup.find_all('div', {'id': 'gs_res_ccl_mid'})[0]
        divs = main_div.find_all('div', {'class': 'gs_r gs_or gs_scl'})
        for div in divs:
            data_cid = div['data-cid']
            print(data_cid)
            title = div.find_all('h3', {'class': 'gs_rt'})[0].text
            infos = div.find_all('div', {'class': 'gs_a'})[0].text
            
            # APA citation
            url_cite = "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=info:%s:scholar.google.com/&output=cite&scirp=0&hl=fr" % (data_cid)
            resp2 = rq.get(url_cite, headers=headers)
            
            # --> extract apa here from resp2
```